# Can we update DOM using GuideBridge object in Adaptive Form?

Tags: aem-6

On AEM Adaptive Form, I have a scenario to format the "Table component" on the review Section dynamically(including changes to no. of column & column names etc.). Though this can be achieved using Jquery, I would like to explore if this can be done using only guideBridge object ? I am able to update the properties of guideBridge object using setProperty fn.; they won't reflect the changes on the Web Page.

I tried to update the properties of guideBridge object using setProperty fn.; they won't reflect the changes on the Web Page.